# NameError: global name 'MyProcess' is not defined

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I wrote a litte script to make a internet radio with a Raspberry pi zero. I first wrote this code on an PI 3. When I try to compile it on my zero I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
File "Radio.py", line 193, in <module> ChangeRadioChannel(0)<br>
File "Radio.py", line 87, in ChangeRadioChannel<br>
MyProcess.stdin.write('q')<br>
NameError: global name 'MyProcess' is not defined<br>
```

I added my some code

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import os
    import keyboard
    from time import sleep
    import shlex, subprocess
    from MAX9744 import MAX9744

    # Channels
    CurrentChannel = 0
    Channels = [
        'Radio P.R.O.S.', 'http://audiostreamen.nl:8012',
        'Star Radio', 'http://internetradio.radiostar.be:8000/;stream.nsv&type=mp3',
    ]
    isPlaying = False

    GPIO.setup(Pin_Next, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(Pin_Prev, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

    def ChangeRadioChannel(choice):
        print('Change radio channel')
        global CurrentChannel 
        global Channels
        global MyProcess
        global Amplifier

        CurrentChannel = CurrentChannel + choice*2

        if CurrentChannel < 0:
            CurrentChannel = len(Channels)-2
        if CurrentChannel > len(Channels)-1:
            CurrentChannel = 0

        MyProcess.stdin.write('q')
        sleep(0.5)
        Amplifier.set_volume(SPEECH_VOLUME)
        os.system('echo "' + Channels[CurrentChannel] + '" | festival --tts')
        Amplifier.set_volume(Volume)
        MyProcess = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '-o', 'local', Channels[CurrentChannel+1]], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        file = open("LastChannel.txt","w")  #Store latest chosen channel in txt file
        file.write(str(CurrentChannel)+"\n")
        file.close()

    def Next(dummy):
        print('Next radio channel')
        ChangeRadioChannel(1)

    def Previous(dummy):
        print('Previous radio channel')
        ChangeRadioChannel(-1)

    GPIO.add_event_detect(Pin_Next, GPIO.RISING, callback = Next, bouncetime = 200)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(Pin_Prev, GPIO.RISING, callback = Previous, bouncetime = 200)

    try:
        try:
            # At boot
            # 1) restore volume
            try: 
                file = open("lastvolume.txt", "r")
                Volume = int(file.read())
                Amplifier.set_volume(Volume)
                file.close()
                print('Volume is set')
            except: pass

            # 2) restore channel
            file = open("LastChannel.txt","r")
            CurrentChannel = int(file.read())
            file.close()
            Amplifier.set_volume(SPEECH_VOLUME)
            os.system('echo "' + Channels[CurrentChannel] + '" | festival --tts')
            Amplifier.set_volume(Volume)
            MyProcess = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '-o', 'local', Channels[CurrentChannel+1]], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        except:
            CurrentChannel=0
            ChangeRadioChannel(0)

        while True:
            sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Somebody any idea? I made my 'MyProcess' global and I imported it
Best regards 
Nick

Comment: You only call `ChangeRadioChannel()` in the `except` block, so by consequence, `MyProcess` hasn't been defined when the function is called.

Comment: @ResetACK No I also call it in the Next() and Previous() functions

Comment: Irrelevant, those functions are never called as far as I can see.

Comment: @ResetACK When I push the switch. the except is only called at the first time

Comment: Like @DecaK suggested, pass `MyProcess` as an argument to `ChangeRadioChannel()`. Your function defintion would be `def ChangeRadioChannel(choice, MyProcess)`, and when you call it: `ChangeRadioChannel(0, MyProcess)`

Comment: Nope Didn't work

Comment: Did you remove the `global MyProcess` line as well?

Comment: yes ofcourse :p

Comment: What I don't get is, Why the error on the Pi zero and not on the Pi 3?